# Ubuntu 17.04 will not read Ethernet but will Wifi

Tags: networking, ethernet

Asus Q550LF 8 Gb i7 1 TB

While upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 Ubuntu renamed the Network card. WiFi worked, but not ethernet.  Proceeded to upgrade to 17.04 and the problem was carried over. Ethernet still works fine with Win 8.1. How can I fix it?

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::dc01:cf88:1f7c:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2605:e000:2342:e700::4  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:2342:e700:f7f:f32c:93b7:3d16  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 10:c3:7b:1e:ea:cd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7963  bytes 2709308 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 785  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2260  bytes 348549 (348.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4763  bytes 311223 (311.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4763  bytes 311223 (311.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 2605:e000:2342:e700:5283:43a0:e0ed:ded  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:2342:e700:d9aa:3889:eb23:538f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:2342:e700::2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::92f1:5157:464b:a1a9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:86:f2:08:b2:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3957  bytes 444699 (444.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 713  bytes 218381 (218.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

AND

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 10:c3:7b:1e:ea:cd
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7900000-f7900fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 6b
       serial: 80:86:f2:08:b2:8b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-20-generic firmware=17.459231.0 ip=192.168.0.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:46 memory:f7800000-f7801fff
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do me a favor and take out all that extra info , I need a basic ifconfig

not -a.

disable wireless when trying to use wired.

what are you settings for wired connection static or dhcp and if dhcp try static with dns static as well 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 is googles dns  and see if you get internet access .

If this doesnt work make sure you go back to dhcp before trying the rest.

can try to bring the device down then back up.

ifconfig eth0 down

ifconfig eth0 up

eth0 = your Ethernet device some times the call name is different a basic ifconfig will reveal the call name on the far left of terminal.

also try

sudo service networking restart

you can also use traceroute to see how far the connection gets to see if its reaching the out side

sudo apt-get install traceroute

EX: traceroute google.com

sometimes you can disable either net through your bios I would make sure its not disabled some where in there. if you never access bios prevously this is most likely not the case .

try

ip addr flush eth0

I found this to be interesting has alot of info on how to discover more info about your either net state .

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

I like this idea use this network manager instead of the stock one witch might not be working correctly

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD